# Redirect URL in push notification on PWA

Tags: firebase, http, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Currently, I'm starting a PWA in Angular. I need to intercep some push notifications and redirect to this application when I click on the notification. I'm using Firebase for the push server.
Today, I can receive push notifications but when i click on one of them, I'm not redirected.
I send my request with Postman, my HTTP request is like :

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Authorization: key=XXXX
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "to":"XXXX",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
      "title": "hello",
      "body": "test message",
      "data": {
        "url": "http://myurl.com"
      }
  }
}
```

In my web application, I receive the following datas :

```
data:
    gcm.notification.content_available: "true"
    gcm.notification.data: "{"url":"http:\/\/myurl.com"}"
    extra: "juice"
from: "300398521917"
notification:
    title: "hello"
    body: "test message"
collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"
```

And, when I click on the receive notification, my application intercept the event and log :

```
action: ""
notification:
    actions: []
    badge: ""
    body: "test message"
    data: null
    dir: "auto"
    icon: ""
    image: ""
    lang: ""
    renotify: false
    requireInteraction: false
    silent: false
    tag: ""
    timestamp: 1582539931548
    title: "hello"
    vibrate: []
```

I would like to refind my url in the data part. Anybody have an idea about this ?

Comment: How did you fixed this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like below its worked for me

{
"to":"XXXX",
"content_available": true,
"notification": {
"title": "hello",
"body": "test message",
"click_action": "https://example.com"

}
}

Answer (score 0):

**self.registration.showNotification** method takes notificationOptions as parameter. So you can pass data object (that will have url and other custom properties that you want to pass) to inside notificationOption object then in **notificationclick** listener, get that object event.notification.data and access all custom properties there.This way you can url to listener.

```
messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
 var dataObj = payload.data; 
 dataObj.someCustomProperty = "xyz";

const notificationOptions = {
  data: dataObj
};

self.registration.showNotification(payload.title,
    notificationOptions);
```

)

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event){
   const nUrl = event. notification.data.customProperty;
```

})

Comment: How do you show foreground notification with onMessage ? I got the foreground noti payload but I can't show as a notification in React

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding clickaction to data . Then I retrieve that data from noti event.

```
const notificationOptions = {
    body: body ?? "Notifications from facebook .",
    icon: icon ?? "/logo.svg",
    badge,
    tag: tag ?? "General",
    renotify: true,
    data: {
        click_action
    }
}
```